# ServiceStack - Post Files Async using JsonServiceClient

Tags: post, servicestack, multipartform-data, .net-6.0

I've trying to POST a single file from one service to another as a stream using an IServiceClient (I'm using the JsonServiceClient). I can achieve this by using code similar to:

```
using (IServiceClient serviceClient = new JsonServiceClient(myBaseUrl)
   serviceClient.PostFile<TResponse>(relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, fileToUpload, fileName, contentType);
```

I see from an [old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954285/servicestack-posting-multiple-files-with-one-post-request) that there is a `JsonHttpClient` that I can't seem to find anymore - gone in favour of the JsonServiceClient?. That had an equivalent async method to achieve the same thing as my code example, but I can't see any way to do this using ServiceStack in the latest version ServiceStack (6.1.x).

Is there a recommended (ServiceStack) way to do this which supports async/await, or do I need to roll my own implementation (only way I can think of doing this will be to use the HttpClient and specify a MultipartFormDataContent on the request)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended ServiceClient for .NET 6+ is to use is the [JsonApiClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client.html#jsonapiclient) which has a number of APIs to [Upload Files from C#](https://docs.servicestack.net/locode/files#uploading-files-from-c).